Scap tool for raspberry pi
I am trying to run DOD scap tool(https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/scap/) for raspberry pi 11 (Bulls eye) but it asking for specific perl library is any one have faced same issues
error:
root@root:/opt/scc# sudo ./cscc --config
/var/rootdirs/opt/scc/lib32/cscc32: error while loading shared libraries: libperl538.so                                                                             : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Tool name : SCC 5.10.1 Raspbian 11 ARMv7
tool link: https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/scap/
I am trying to do security audit of the system using the scap tool by DOD, the  "SCC 5.10.1 Raspbian 11 ARMv7" tool should have worked fine for the my armv7 based raspberry pi but facing dependency issues
